# How do i perform grouped ranking in MySQL with row ties?

Tags: mysql

### ID_STUDENT | ID_CLASS | GRADE | RANK

```
2      |    1     |  90   |  1
1      |    1     |  90   |  1
3      |    1     |  90   |  1
4      |    1     |  70   |  4
6      |    2     |  90   |  1
1      |    2     |  80   |  2
5      |    2     |  78   |  3
7      |    3     |  90   |  1
6      |    3     |  50   |  2
```

How should i sort and rank the data to get the above result? Thanks in advance

Comment: what result you want ???

Comment: It is not clear what your problem is. Please state the question more clearly.  In addition, you will probably find there is already an answer on stackoverflow on the use of grouping and ranking.

Answer (score 0):

One method is with a subquery:

```
select sc.*,
       (select count(*) + 1
        from studentclass sc2
        where sc2.grade > sc.grade and sc2.id_class = sc.id_class
       ) as rank
from studentclass sc order by id_class, grade;
```

In ANSI SQL (and most other databases), this is provided by the `rank()` function.  You might be interested in the differences between `rank()`, `dense_rank()`, and `row_number()`.